# Python if loop time.sleep only execute once

Tags: python

Below code is for a PIR sensor written in Python.

**What it should do**

When the sensor was activate the first time, it should wait for 10 second once and then keep printing  "Intruder detected" until the sensor was = 0.

**what is actually do**

Rather than waiting 10s once, the code below wait ever 10s when the pir sensor was tigger.

Why is that?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)         #Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)         #LED output pin
while True:
       i=GPIO.input(11)
       if i==0:                 #When output from motion sensor is LOW
             print "No intruders",i
             GPIO.output(3, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
             time.sleep(0.1)
       elif i==1:               #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
             time.sleep(10)     #This should be only run once when the pir sensor is trigger
             print "Intruder detected",i
             GPIO.output(3, 1)  #Turn ON LED
             time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `GPIO.input(11)` does go back to zero? Maybe do a `print i` before the `if` to check.

Comment: Question is simple or even silly, but question's format is good. It clearly shows the expected behave and the current behave with a code snippet. I don't think it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remember if it was triggererd:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)         # Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)         # LED output pin
wasTriggered = False            # not yet triggered
while True:
       i=GPIO.input(11)
       if i == 0:                          # When output from motion sensor is LOW
             print "No intruders",i
             wasTriggered = False          # reset trigger if True else does nothing
             GPIO.output(3, 0)             # Turn OFF LED
             time.sleep(0.1)
       elif i == 1:                        # When output from motion sensor is HIGH
             if wasTriggered == False:     # already triggered ?
                 time.sleep(10)            # only run once when the pir sensor is trigger
                 print "Intruder detected",i
                 GPIO.output(3, 1)         # Turn ON LED
                 wasTriggered = True       # set was triggered 
             time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is creating a "memory" - it will only reset once the Sensor reports one `0` on pin 11. You might want to switch the "Led goes red + Output text" and the sleep around to make it more "snappy" - meaning it will react immediately to the sensor change and then pause for 10s instead of pausing for 10s and then switch the light & print text which would disconnect the "Act"->"React" sequence.

Comment: I am trying to have a 10 second delay before the alarm trigger. So switch led + output text and sleep around won't work.

Comment: @butbut If you have a usecase for it - ok, from a "Guard watches for Trespasser" perspective it seems a bad idea ;) - I did not switch things around so answer should work as you intended